# Chi Square Contingency Table - Formula Derivation

Tags: statistics, independence, actuarial-science, chi-squared

A chi-square distribution is constructed from normal random variables $X_i i=1,...n$ , each with normal distribution and mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.  Transforming to standard normal and squaring, i.e.:

$$\frac{(X_i - \bar{X})^2}{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)}\sim N(0,1)^2$$

Then add these over all your $n$ random variables, then you get $\chi^2_{n-1}$ - a chi-square with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.

For contingency tables, suppose there are $k$ categories of observations $O_i, i = 1, \ldots , k,$ each with probability $p_i$. The statistic
we’re proposing, assuming $O_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}$, is:

$$\frac{(O_i-np_i)^2}{\operatorname{Var}(O_i)} \sim N(0,1)^2$$

The variance of each observation is $np_i(1-p_i)$

For contingency tables, a test to see if the underlying mean is the same across categories, the standard equation taught for calculating the Chi-Square statistic is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(O_i-np_i)^2}{np_i} \sim \chi^2_{n-1}$$

So, where in the equation for assessing contingency tables does the term $(1-p_i)$ disappear to?

Comment: I think that this is because the test is connected to the poisson distribution where mean = variance.

Comment: See [_this answer_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2737244/pearsons-test-for-contingency-tables/2737865#2737865) (ignoring comments of questioner who had his/her own extraneous agenda).

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE A chi-square distribution is constructed from normal random variables through transforming to standard normal and squaring, i.e.: $$\frac{(X_i - \bar{X_i})^2}{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)}\sim N(0,1)^2$$ Then add these over all your random variables, say $n$ of them, then you get $\chi^2_{n-1}$ chi-square with $n-1$ degrees of freedom. END QUOTE That is rather misleadingly stated. if you have $$\frac{(X_i - \operatorname{E}(X_i))^2}{\operatorname{Var}(X_i)}\sim N(0,1)^2$$ then their sum is distributed as $\chi^2_n,$ under the usual assumptions including independence. If$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$If in addition to independence you assume all of the means expectations are equal and all of the variances are equal, and if you use $\bar X$ instead of $\operatorname E(X),$ then the sum is distributed as $\chi^2_{n-1}. $ To say that in general without these assumptions you get a $\chi^2_{n-1}$ distribution by adding $n$ terms is not true.

Comment: What do you mean by saying the categories are independent? There is a chi-square test for equality of all $p_i,$ and there is a chi-square test of a hypothesis that specifies their values, and there is a chi-square test of independence or homogeneity in an $n\times m$ table, and that last does not look like what you've described. You're using words quite loosely.

Comment: Maybe tomorrow I'll post an answer here if nobody else does it first.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, I updated the question to clarify the initial motivating facts.  I also clarified that I meant the test was to determine if the underlying mean is the same across observations.

Answer (score 0):

**One experiment.** Illustration in terms of rolling a fair die. Suppose I use R statistical software to roll a fair
die $n=600$ times, observing counts $X = (104, 96, 96, 104, 101, 100)$ of the respective faces $1, 2, \dots, 6.$ The expected number for each face is $E=100.$
[The code with `rle` is a quick way to get the vector $X$ in a form usable
by other functions.]

```
set.seed(420);  x = sample(1:6, 600, rep=T)
table(x)
x
  1   2   3   4   5   6 
104  96  95 104 101 100 

set.seed(420); X = rle(sort(sample(1:6,600,rep=T)))$lengths
[1] 104  96  95 104 101 100
```

Then the chi-squared statistic is $Q = \sum_{i=1}^6 \frac{(X_i-E)^2}{E} = 0.747 < 11.07,$ so in this particular (unusually well behaved) experiment, there is no evidence
that the die is unfair. Under the null hypothesis that all faces are
equally likely, $Q \stackrel{\text{aprx}}{\sim} \mathsf{Chisq}(df=5),$
so the critical value is $q^* = 11.07.$

```
X = c(104, 96, 95, 104, 101, 100);  E = 100
Q = sum((X-E)^2/X);  Q
## 0.7474179
qchisq(.95, 5)
## 11.0705
```

**Many experiments.** Now we seek to illustrate that $Q$ has very nearly the
claimed chi-squared distribution, which has $E(Q) = 5$ and $Var(Q) = 10.$ We do many 600-roll experiments
in order to get an idea of the distribution of $Q.$

```
set.seed(4321)
m = 10^5;  Q = numeric(m);  n = 600;  E = 100
for(i in 1:m) {
  X = rle(sort(sample(1:6,n,rep=T)))$lengths
  Q[i] = sum((X-E)^2/E) }
mean(Q);  var(Q);  quantile(Q, .95)
## 5.004733  # aprx E(Q) = 5
## 9.973967  # aprx Var(Q) = 10
##    95% 
##  11.02    # aprx c with P(Q < c)=.95;  c = 11.07
hist(q, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main="Simulated Dist'n of Q with CHISQ(5) Density")
curve(dchisq(x, 5), add=T, lwd=2, col="red")
```

The histogram below shows 100,000 values of $Q$ and the red curve is
the density of $\mathsf{Chisq}(df = 5).$

[image]

The theory that supports the approximate chi-squared distribution of $Q$
is asymptotic. Simulation studies have shown that the approximation is
useful for doing goodness-of-fit tests, provided there are enough 'rolls of the die' so that $E > 5,$ which
is certainly true here.

Comment: In answer to the question in your last sentence, there never was a $(1−p_i).$ In the foundational theory of this kind of chi-sq test, the $X_i$ are assumed to be Poisson, so the general term is $\left(\frac{X_i−\lambda_i}{\sqrt{\lambda_i}}\right)^2 \stackrel{\text{aprx}}{\sim} \mathsf{Chisq}(df=1),$ for $\lambda_i$ sufficiently large. Linear constraints involved in estimating $\lambda_i$ reduce the df of the sum.

Comment: Thank you for that, the simulation was very interesting.  It uses a Uniform distribution as the underlying distribution, correct?  I'm more interested in the very last part of the question, which you claim is due to the fact that the theory underpinning the construction of the statistic is that $X_i$ are Poisson.  I can definitely see how the math works there.  But how does one go from there to the $X_i$ being normally distributed?  I have a feeling the central limit theorem will come in here, but I just cant make the connection.

Comment: Key point is that for sufficiently large $\lambda,$ Poisson is approximately normal (much like binom). // _My main goal_ was to show that the "chi-sq stat" Q really has nearly a chi-sq dist'n and with df=5. This is suggested by asymptotic theory, but in specific (finite) instances it is worthwhile doing a reality check. // In some sense, all simulation is ultimately based on UNIF(0,1). But here the uniform RVs are used to sample at random to emulate rolling fair dice. So closer at hand, you can view the `sample` function as the basis of this simulation.